# Where can you download an installer file for PyQT?

Tags: python, pyqt

Where can you download an installer file for PyQT? I am unable to figure out how to build it with the source code. Is there a prepackaged version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) (http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download, found by doing a google search for pyqt installer :-) )

Comment: I was going to answer with [pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), but see that the [PyQT page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt/4.8.1) there points to the above page.

Comment: i found this too, but it the installer package is windows only, but thanks anyway, because i use windows and mac